# Add subtitle line by line dynamically to a video element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I wanted to know if this is currently possible

below is my HTML:

```
<video src="something.mp4"> </video>
```

I also have an array of `Object` that has all the captions I need to display...

example:

```
captions_array = [
    {start: 0, end: 2, message: "hello"}, 
    {start: 3, end: 4, message: "how"}, 
    {start: 5, end: 8, message: "are"}
]
```

Now based on the video's current time I want to just pick one caption out of this array and display that, remove that when needed, and display another...

Note:

**1.** I must supply captions on video playback, by choosing text from that array dynamically.

**2.** I cannot use any subtitle file (VTT), I get captions from this array only

**3.** I can't do anything on the backend, I want to do this on the front-end in the browser only.

**Edit**: In response to answers to this question:

**4. I cannot use source element inside thee video tag**

**5. The captions Array will get populated with time dynamically**

You can use this mp4 URL to create a short demo: 
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4

Comment: @VC.One please do not put comments that are irrelevant to the question asked above. It crowds the comment section.

Comment: Reading later is not a problem. You don't want a history of "not accepting" or "not upvoting" useful answers. This will affect your account later on (_eg:_ a 1 week asking ban, although that one only happens to people who ask multiple bad down-voted questions). I quietly remove such comments when the accept happens.

Answer (score 5):

You can create [WebVTT files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API) from the browser directly and load them using a blob:// URI.

[The syntax](https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#file-parsing) for WebVTT is quite strict but also quite simple to grasp.

So if we say that your `start` and `end` values do represent seconds in the media we could make a generator this way:

```js
const captions_array = [
  { start: 0, end: 2, message: "hello" }, 
  { start: 3, end: 4, message: "how" }, 
  { start: 5, end: 8, message: "are" }
];
const VTTFile = makeVTT( captions_array );
const vid = document.querySelector( "video" );
const track = document.createElement( "track" );
track.kind = "captions";
track.label = "English";
track.srclang = "en";
track.src = URL.createObjectURL( VTTFile );
vid.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", (evt) => {
  track.mode = "showing";
  vid.textTracks[0].mode = "showing"; // thanks Firefox 
});
vid.append( track );

function makeVTT( array ) {
  const text = array.reduce( (str, { start, end, message }, index) => {
    // you would also have to make a "seconds to timestamp" parser
    // but I leave it to the reader as an exercise
    return str + `
00:00:${ start.toFixed(3).padStart(6, "0") } --> 00:00:${ end.toFixed(3).padStart(6, "0") }
${ message }`;
  }, `WEBVTT`);
  return new Blob( [ text ], { type: "text/plain" } );
}
```

```css
video { max-height: 100vh; max-width: 100vw; }
```

```html
<video controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: @Kaiidoo I forgot to mention, I cannot use the source attribute, and the captions array will also be populated with time, for example, if there are 3 captions in it right now, later I might have 20 more...

Comment: @xaovnumwsercz why couldn't you use the source element? If you can run js, you can. Then, if it's populated dynamically, just create a new file at every update.

Comment: @Kaiidoo I am developing for iOS safari, where I have two video elements playing videos simultaneously... there are many limitations such as I cannot take any div to fullscreen other than video element and such... I cannot have source element also in my use-case, got It from apple docs...

Comment: @xaovnumwsercz that sounds like a very weird limitation, are you sure it's what the docs say? Could you link to it? But anyway, you don't need that element here

Comment: @Kaiido it isn't a limit as far as I know but we shall see from the link Asker provides. Apple pushed for VTT in browser so it's strange that they later refuse a `<video>` to have a source for the subtitles in their own browser. Anyways if not using dynamic VTT file, I don't how they will display subtitle text since it will have to be inside a `<div>` positioned above the video (a problem when video itself goes fullscreen but not the text div).

Comment: the limitation exists because in order to autoplay a video in safari for iOS, I have to let user action play a video in a specific video tag and use the SAME video tag for future autoplays. In this case, I cannot use the source tags.

@VC.One maybe try playing two HLS live streams in two video elements side by side in iOS safari with autoplay, you'll know more about the depth of limitations iOS safari has to offer.

Comment: @Kaiido these subtitles added to the video element are a part of the video element now right? My main intention to get the answer to my question was to be able to show subtitles when the video element is in fullscreen (because I cannot take my subtitles UI to fullscreen in iOS safari due to limitations(

Comment: @xaovnumwsercz When you create `<video>` then everything including multiple `.src` is part of that same video tag until you close its setup with `</video>`. You will have to test with a timer if dynamically changing `.src` of subtitles at later time works as expected

Comment: yes, that I'll have to since my subtitle array gets populated dynamically I'll have to create a new blob every time it updates and provide it to the video

Comment: So that's what I thought, you misunderstood your situation. You can very well change the source of a video while it's playing without having to request a new user gesture. Just call the `.load()` method of the video element. And yes you will have to generate new Blobs, which once again is not a problem at all, simply remember to call `URL.revokeObjectURL(track.src)`  before updating it.